# WP Rest API v2 filter and display latest post with specific tag

Tags: posts, json, rest-api, wp-api

I need to display the latest post with a specific tag.

Example:  User tags a post 'featured', but forgets to untag earlier posts.

So I want to ensure that the latest post tagged 'featured' is what displays on other sites.

https://my-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags/&filterbylatestdatesomehow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually find [extensive documentation on wordpress.org.](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts)

But let's have a look at this particular example:

```
https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5&tags=3
```

The `5` in there is the number of posts you want returned.
The `3` is the id of the tag you want to limit the posts too.

If you want to limit to a category use `categories` instead. But you'd have figured that out yourself after looking at the documentation, right? ;-)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!  Yup. .I am going straight to the documentation :)